# NODE.JS MSSQL utilizar função NEWID() do SQL como valor de uma variável

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Boa tarde!

Tem uma função do SQL (NEWID()) que gera uma chave única com este formato: '6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF'

Porém, quando tento popular uma coluna com o valor NEWID() através do meu servidor NODE invés de ter o valor da chave, a coluna fica com uma string 'NEWID()'

veja a conexão de exemplo abaixo:

```
function createCotacao() {
let conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
let req = new sql.Request(conn);

conn.connect(function (err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } 
req.input('chave', sql.VarChar, 'NEWID()');
req.query("INSERT INTO columname (chave) VALUES (@chave)");
```

Se eu tento utilizar NEWID() sem as aspas, ele me retorna um erro, e já tentei usar SELECT NEWID() ou então substituir as aspas por aquela template string, mas não consigo o valor da chave... Alguém saberia me dizer no que estou pecando? ou então me dizer algum workaround para conseguir gerar esta chave como valor da coluna através do meu servidor NODE.

PS: Estou utilizando o módulo MSSQL para conexão com o SQL SERVER.

Comment: Por que você não tira o `input` e colocar `NEWID()` diretamente no lugar do `@chave`?

Comment: putz, brigadão! aqui funcionou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NEWID()` é uma função interna do `sql-server`, ela não pode ser usada sendo processada no código assim:
`req.input('chave', sql.VarChar, 'NEWID()');`

Para usá-la, inclua diretamente no comando SQL:

`"INSERT INTO columname (chave) VALUES (NEWID())"`

Assim, quando executar a query, todo o comando será passado para o banco de dados executar, que vai executar corretamente o `NEWID()`, da mesma forma que qualquer outra função/comando interno do banco, como `MAX()`, `DATEDIFF()` ou `CAST()`, por exemplo.

Comment: caraca, eu que estava sendo sendo burro... muito obrigado! funcionou aqui!

Comment: tranquilo, é um detalhe acontece :)